# I want to array parameter with Zend router in ZF1

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-controller-router

I want to customize url by Zend_Controller_Router.

I know the way when parameter is 1.

like this url

```
 /fruits?name=banana
```

is able to write by Zend router

/fruits/banana

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
'fruits/:name/*',
array('controller'=>'fruits','action'=>'index')
);
```

I cant get banana like this.

```
$fruits = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name',NULL);
```

But I don't know the way to code Zend Router when paramters are more than 1

I want to this url

```
/fruits?name[]=banana&name[]=apple&name[]=grape
```

to following

```
/fruits/banana/apple/grape
```

and I want to get them in contoroller like this

```
$fruits = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name',NULL);
```

I hope get parameters like this array

```
$fruits = array(
'banana',
'apple',
'grape'
);
```

please let me know the way.